# ReactiveCrudRepository is not found by Spring to be injected into other classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, reactive-programming

**Problem:**

I have a `ReactiveCrudRepository` which I want to use in a `RestController` but it's not found by Spring to be injected anymore. Before I refactored the repository towards becoming reactive (it was a `CrudRepository` before) the repository was found and injected by Spring.

**Now I get this error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in de.shinythings.microservices.core.product.services.ProductServiceImpl required a bean of type 'de.shinythings.microservices.core.product.persistence.ProductRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'de.shinythings.microservices.core.product.persistence.ProductRepository' in your configuration.
```

**The repository looks like this:** [link to GitHub](https://github.com/Partyschaum/hands-on-microservices/blob/go-reactive/microservices/product-service/src/main/kotlin/de/shinythings/microservices/core/product/persistence/ProductRepository.kt)

```kotlin
interface ProductRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<ProductEntity, String> {

    fun findByProductId(productId: Int): Mono<ProductEntity>
}
```

**The rest controller looks like this:** [link to GitHub](https://github.com/Partyschaum/hands-on-microservices/blob/go-reactive/microservices/product-service/src/main/kotlin/de/shinythings/microservices/core/product/services/ProductServiceImpl.kt)

```kotlin
@RestController
class ProductServiceImpl(
        private val repository: ProductRepository,
        private val mapper: ProductMapper,
        private val serviceUtil: ServiceUtil
) : ProductService { // implementation left out here }
```

**What I tried so far:**

I enabled the `debug` flag in my `application.yml` to learn more from the output but this did not generate useful insights.

I removed the `ProductRepository` dependency from the `ProductServiceImpl` class to not get the above error when starting up Spring.

Then I wrote myself a little test to ask the `ApplicationContext` for the `ProductRepository` specifically:

```
@SpringBootTest
class BeanLoadingDebugging {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val bean = applicationContext.getBean(ProductRepository::class.java)

        Assert.notNull(bean, "Bean not found!")
    }
}
```

**This also does not work!**

So it seems that this repository just does not want to be found. I double-checked this and tried the same with the not reactive `CrudRepository` and this was found. ‍♂️

**Full disclosure:**

I'm new to Spring / Spring Boot and happy for any advice here.

[The complete code can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Partyschaum/hands-on-microservices/tree/go-reactive).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, You have to update the dependency from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`.

Second, enable reactive support like below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("de.shinythings")
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories 
class RecommendationServiceApplication
```

After these two changes i can see the test `de.shinythings.microservices.core.recommendation.BeanLoadingDebugging` success.

Look more into [Spring reactive mongo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories)

Comment: Thank you so very much! Adding the missing dependency fixed it. Adding `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` was not necessary.

Comment: Either you or OP is smoking something because the question never mentioned MongoDB

Comment: @TheCornInspector You need to look at all the details from the question. https://github.com/Partyschaum/hands-on-microservices/blob/go-reactive/microservices/product-service/build.gradle.kts#L28